# Merge two plots into one with label

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a code like this:
Having this commands:

```
library(stm)
gadarian <- gadarian
K<-c(5,10,15)
temp<-textProcessor(documents=gadarian$open.ended.response,metadata=gadarian)
out <- prepDocuments(temp$documents, temp$vocab, temp$meta)
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta
set.seed(02138)
K<-c(5,10,15)
df1 <- searchK(documents, vocab, K, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
df2 <- searchK(documents, vocab, K, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
```

We can plot the results of df1:

```
plot(df1$results$K, df1$results$heldout, type = "p", main = "Held-Out Likelihood", 
    xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Held-Out Likelihood", ask = TRUE)
lines(df1$results$K, df1$results$heldout, lty = 1, col = 1)
```

and for df2 using this:

```
plot(df2$results$K, df2$results$heldout, type = "p", main = "Held-Out Likelihood", 
    xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Held-Out Likelihood", ask = TRUE)
lines(df2$results$K, df2$results$heldout, lty = 1, col = 1)
```

How is it possible to merge this two plot into one having different colors for every line and add a box in the right up corner of the graph which will have the color line and next to it the label likehood_score_df1 and likehood_score_df2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$heldout,
     ylim=range(c(df1$results$heldout,df2$results$heldout)),
     xlim=range(c(df1$results$K,df2$results$K)), type="b",col="red",
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Held-out Likelihood",
     main="Held-out Likelihood")

lines(df2$results$K,df2$results$heldout,col="green", type="b")

# Add a legend
legend(5, -5.52, legend=c("Likelihood score 1", "Likelihood score 2"),
   col=c("red", "green"), lty=1, cex=0.8, pch = 1)
```

Here you have to provide your x and y corodinates where you want to add your legend. A much better solution is dynamic positioning of the legend using

```
legend(locator(1), legend=c("Likelihood score 1", "Likelihood score 2"),
       col=c("red", "green"), lty=1, cex=0.8, pch = 1)
```

After running this click where you want to have the legend within the plot.
[image]

The code is bit messy but works.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to reproduce the example using the code but I receive in the plot only the last line and not both

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using ggplot2. If you want to add points or adjust the layout its quite easy to do so. I hope the example gets you started :)

For future questions it would be helpful, if you could provide a **minimal** working example (i.e. if you could just have provided df1$result and df2$result it would have been fine)

```
df1$results %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group="likehood_score_df1") %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(df2$results %>%
                     dplyr::mutate(group="likehood_score_df2")) %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=K, y=heldout, color=group)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
  ggplot2::labs(x="Number of Topics (K)",
                y="Held-Out Likelihood",
                title="Held-Out Likelihood") + 
  ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
  ggplot2::theme(legend.position=c(0.9,0.9),
                 legend.direction="vertical")
```

[image]